# Why accepted two same 5-tuple socket when concurrent connect to the server?

Tags: sockets, go, networking, tcp

server.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    _ "net/http/pprof"
    "sync"
    "syscall"
)

type ConnSet struct {
    data  map[int]net.Conn
    mutex sync.Mutex
}

func (m *ConnSet) Update(id int, conn net.Conn) error {
    m.mutex.Lock()
    defer m.mutex.Unlock()
    if _, ok := m.data[id]; ok {
        fmt.Printf("add: key %d existed \n", id)
        return fmt.Errorf("add: key %d existed \n", id)
    }
    m.data[id] = conn
    return nil
}

var connSet = &ConnSet{
    data: make(map[int]net.Conn),
}

func main() {
    setLimit()

    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":12345")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    go func() {
        if err := http.ListenAndServe(":6060", nil); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("pprof failed: %v", err)
        }
    }()

    var connections []net.Conn
    defer func() {
        for _, conn := range connections {
            conn.Close()
        }
    }()

    for {
        conn, e := ln.Accept()
        if e != nil {
            if ne, ok := e.(net.Error); ok && ne.Temporary() {
                log.Printf("accept temp err: %v", ne)
                continue
            }

            log.Printf("accept err: %v", e)
            return
        }
        port := conn.RemoteAddr().(*net.TCPAddr).Port
        connSet.Update(port, conn)
        go handleConn(conn)
        connections = append(connections, conn)
        if len(connections)%100 == 0 {
            log.Printf("total number of connections: %v", len(connections))
        }
    }
}

func handleConn(conn net.Conn) {
    io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, conn)
}

func setLimit() {
    var rLimit syscall.Rlimit
    if err := syscall.Getrlimit(syscall.RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rLimit); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    rLimit.Cur = rLimit.Max
    if err := syscall.Setrlimit(syscall.RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rLimit); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    log.Printf("set cur limit: %d", rLimit.Cur)
}
```

client.go

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

var portFlag = flag.Int("port", 12345, "port")

type ConnSet struct {
    data  map[int]net.Conn
    mutex sync.Mutex
}

func (m *ConnSet) Update(id int, conn net.Conn) error {
    m.mutex.Lock()
    defer m.mutex.Unlock()
    if _, ok := m.data[id]; ok {
        fmt.Printf("add: key %d existed \n", id)
        return fmt.Errorf("add: key %d existed \n", id)
    }
    m.data[id] = conn
    return nil
}

var connSet = &ConnSet{
    data: make(map[int]net.Conn),
}

func echoClient() {
    addr := fmt.Sprintf("127.0.0.1:%d", *portFlag)
    dialer := net.Dialer{}
    conn, err := dialer.Dial("tcp", addr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    port := conn.LocalAddr().(*net.TCPAddr).Port
    connSet.Update(port, conn)
    defer conn.Close()

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        s := fmt.Sprintf("%s", strconv.Itoa(i))
        _, err := conn.Write([]byte(s))
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("write error: ", err)
        }
        b := make([]byte, 1024)
        _, err = conn.Read(b)
        switch err {
        case nil:
            if string(bytes.Trim(b, "\x00")) != s {
                log.Printf("resp req not equal, req: %d, res: %s", i, string(bytes.Trim(b, "\x00")))
            }
        case io.EOF:
            fmt.Println("eof")
            break
        default:
            fmt.Println("ERROR", err)
            break
        }
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Hour)
    if err := conn.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Printf("client conn close err: %s", err)
    }
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    setLimit()
    before := time.Now()
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 20000; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            echoClient()
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(time.Now().Sub(before))
}

func setLimit() {
    var rLimit syscall.Rlimit
    if err := syscall.Getrlimit(syscall.RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rLimit); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    rLimit.Cur = rLimit.Max
    if err := syscall.Setrlimit(syscall.RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rLimit); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    log.Printf("set cur limit: %d", rLimit.Cur)
}
```

running command

```
go run server.go
---
go run client.go
```

server running screenshot

[image]

The client simultaneously initiates 20,000 connections to the server, and the server accepted two remotePort connections that are exactly the same (in a extremely short period of time).

I try to use [tcpconn.py](https://gist.github.com/ariesdevil/408e102a8e61d2371fabaf6a3155cf80) from bcc (patched from [tcpconnect.py](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/tcpconnect.py) by add skc_num(aka: local_port)) 
[image]

[tcpaccept.py](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/tcpaccept.py) 
[image]
tracing the connection, and also finds that the remote port is duplicated on the server side when there is no duplicate on the client side

In my understanding, the 5-tuple of the socket will not be duplicated, Why the server accepted two sockets with exactly the same remote port?

My test environment:

Fedora 31, kernel version 5.3.15 x86_64
and
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, kernel version 4.19.1 x86_64

go version go1.13.5 linux/amd64

wireshark:
server TCP Keep-Alive to both ACK & PSH+ACK
[image: dup flow]

server TCP Keep-Alive to PSH+ACK only
[image: no dup]

Comment: Bizarre. Do both connections work? i.e. can you send and receive data correctly via both of them?

Comment: such as

server
```
conn1.Write([]byte("1"))
conn2.Write([]byte("2"))

conn1.Write([]byte("3"))
conn2.Write([]byte("4"))

```
client can received `14`  from the conncetion

Comment: @user207421   Both connections works. I tried to write a few data after accept the two connections on the server. The client can read the data written by the both connections, but not all of the messages can be received

Comment: Define 'not all of the messages can be received'. Can they be received by connections from unique 5-tuples? or is there just a bug in your code?

Comment: Is this really the code you're running? The server discards all data read without writing anything back, but the client is expecting a response. The duplicate error on the server side could happen if the client closes a connection, and then reuses the same port it used before, but that doesn't look possible from the code.

Comment: ... and if the server closes the connection without reading all the pending data, the connection will be reset rather than closed, which will permit the reuse of the client port.

Comment: @BurakSerdar the client-side will block on read op so that there is no port reusing happen.

Comment: @user207421 and the server never close any connections in these code snippets until the main exit.

Comment: @BurakSerdar  the code is runnable. server block on accept new connection, and client block on read from connection, both client and server will not close the connections, I validate this by https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/tcptracer.py.  
I capture localhost network traffic by wireshark, 56186, 57376, 47892 have duplicate problems. other ports, such as 42002, do not have this problem. can you help me to see what is wrong?   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GsxwXr3306KnIMm5rhsdQB4go0BoAeXv/view

Comment: On the server side, try reading from a duplicate connection when you find it, see if you get an EOF error. That means, the connection was closed.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem on my system (Centos 7). Have you tried running this in a different environment?

Comment: @BurakSerdar Thank you for responding, the reproducing is not steady, we can reproduce on (fedora desktop kernel 5.3, ubuntu-desktop kernel 5.0, ubuntu-desktop kernel 4.19, ubuntu-server kernel 5.0, Gentoo kernel 4.9), but we cannot reproduce on (ubuntu (both desktop and server) kernel 4.15, Gentoo kernel 4.4). And even on the machines that can be reproduced, not every attempt can be made.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your Go code. I think what's happening is closed (or reset) connections, and as I said before, you can test this hypothesis by testing your connection once you find a duplicate port was used. Then, if you have the time and will, you can try diagnosing why those connections are closing (resetting).

Comment: @BurakSerdar Based on your suggestion, I tried it https://gist.github.com/dzdx/35363a04ea9582cd9b0b324e44a7c1c4   only one connection can be read, but another connection is not closed at the time

Comment: @dzdx, what do you mean by "another connection is not closed"? Can you read from it without error? If there is error, what is the error?

Comment: @BurakSerdar "is not closed" means the socket is exist and we can fire a read op on it. The error is shown here: https://gist.github.com/dzdx/35363a04ea9582cd9b0b324e44a7c1c4#gistcomment-3128816

Comment: The "connection reset" error shows that the socket is closed. The "connection timeout" shows that one side is waiting for an ack that never arrives. Maybe it missed the reset? Either case, the other end of the socket is closed, and somehow one side missed it. My guess is the message was really lost, or there is a tcp stack related thing going in here. This is unlikely related to the go implementation.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Yup, programming language is irrelevant, we can reproduce it use other programming languages.

Comment: @dzdx, what's the status of TCP connection? it is possible that one of the duplicate is in CLOSE_WAIT state and another in ESTABLISHED state

Answer (score 1):

Connection is added to the map `data  map[int]net.Conn` when it is established, but when connection is closed it is not removed from the map. So if connection gets closed its port become free and could be reused by an Operation System for next connection. That's a reason why you can see duplicate ports.

Try to remove port from map when they are get closed.